# How to install in the ide 2 different version of the same component library?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have one project who need the version 1.0.0 of a visual components library (devExpress). I also have another project who need the version 2.0.0 of the devExpress. Probleme in delphi **I can install only one version of the library**. How can I handle this ?

Comment: I guess many people would solve this with several VMs (using e.g. VMWare, Parallels, Oracle VM), each with their own installation. It is what I would do. I doubt you can install different versions of the same framework in the IDE, unless you manage to rename **every class and every source file** in one of the frameworks and then to recompile that entire framework. Not very easy, I guess.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Indeed, and the Devex VCL library contains so many packages, it would be no fun at all.  Devex dropped support for D7 several versions ago, and it's possible (because I've done it) to have a parallel D7-specific install with its own isolated folders for source and packages and path entry.  But in the same Delphi version?  I don't think so ...

Comment: FYI. The last version of DevEx to support Delphi 7, was 14.2. My Delphi 7 Devex projects are on a different PC.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid possible source file collisions, installing several different versions of DevExpress VCL controls on a single machine is not supported. However, there are workarounds provided in the [How to have several build versions installed on one machine](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18518/how-to-have-several-build-versions-installed-on-one-machine) article.

Comment: thanks, but I would like a solution for any visual control library (not only devEx)

Comment: The techniques described in the linked article are not Devex-specific and should in principle work with any VCL library, but would be quite a lot of work to set up and maintain.  Using different set-ups in different VMs, as suggested by @RudyVelthuis is way easier ...